Transforming Principal quintic into Jerrard Form
So for the quintic
$x^5+2x^2-x+1=0$
I was wondering how I would get this transformed to its Bring Jerrard form. I was able to get the substitution
$y=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$
I know that c is a free parameter but I was wondering how to continue.
since I got the quartic terms which were
$6a-5d-4=0$
for the cubic terms i got
$12a^{2}+5ba-4ca-24da-10a-2b^{2}+10d^{2}-12b+6bc+5c+16d-2=0$
and for the quadratic terms I got
$11a^{3}+10a^{2}b-10a^{2}c-36a^{2}d-9a^{2}+2ab^{2}+5ac^{2}+36ad^{2}-26ab+12abc+6ac-15abd+12acd+30ad-2a-4b^{3}+2c^{3}-10d^{3}-12b^{2}-4bc^{2}-12c^{2}-24d^{2}+3b+5b^{2}c+4bc+13c+6b^{2}d+36bd-18bcd-15cd+6d-4=0$
How would I continue to eliminate the quadratic, cubic and quartic terms? How do I know what to set c equal to? I was also wondering if we can even convert this to a form that is solvable, like transforming the principal form quintic into a De Moivre Quintic, or the Kondo–Brumer quintic.

Ah, I'm late. Have you figured it out yet?
I'll answer anyway. Pardon the terrible formatting, this is one of my first answers.
What you need to do first is factor $c, c^2,$ and $c^3$ out of the cubic and quadratic terms. This will be important later. Now, we set the quartic and cubic terms to zero. You set $$6a - 5d - 4 = 12a^2 + 5ba - 4ca - 24da - 10a - 2b^2 + 10d^2 - 12b + 6bc + 5c + 16d - 2=0$$, but since you need to leave c a free parameter for later, you also set $-4a + 6b + 5 = 0$ (the coefficient of $c$ after factoring) too.
After you finish up all the messy algebra, you need to remove the quadratic term. Factoring out $c, c^2,$ and $c^3$ turns it into a cubic, of the form:
$$Ac^3 + Bc^2 + Cc + D$$
, which can be solved in any way you want. Pick any root, they all set the quadratic term to 0.
Clean up the algebra, and voila! You now have a quintic of the form $z^5 + \alpha z + \beta$!

How would I get the cubic though? I tried but i got nowhere.

Oh, I'm not late. Cool.
Lemme elaborate.
If you're using something like Wolfram Alpha, it will dump you a massive equation that I'd rather not write here. The point is, you take the quadratic term, and factor c^3, c^2, and c out of the coefficient. This gives you a cubic. Wolfram won't factor it out for you, you'll have to take the coefficient and do it yourself. Makes sense?
